# with Zend\Db\Sql\Select can I manipulate the order that the SQL parts are put together?

Tags: sql, pdo, zend-framework2, firebird

I am using PDO Firebird with Zend\Db.

This is fine until i want to limit the number of records returned. I am using this code;

```
$select = $this->getSelect()
               ->limit($limit);
```

Which produces this SQL;

```
SELECT "MODELS".* FROM "MODELS" limit '10'
```

However firebird needs SQL like this;

```
SELECT first 10 "MODELS".* FROM "MODELS"
```

I can change the word 'limit' to 'first' by using this statement;

```
$select->setSpecification('limit', 'first %1$s');
```

But I can't figure out how i get it to put the limit (first) clause at the beginning of the SQL and not at the end.

I can't find the code in Zend\Db\Sql\Select that puts the SQL parts together.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without implementing your own Select statement.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, since version 2.0 [Firebird supports ROWS clause](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-select.html#langrefupd25-select-rows) which is in the end of the statement. So I quess you need to use something like

```
$select->setSpecification('limit', 'ROWS %1$s');
```

but I'm not familiar with the `setSpecification` syntax so you might need to change the format string.

Comment: This is very interesting and almost solves the problem. The concept is slightly different though. e.g. LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20 would equate to FIRST 10 SKIP 20. But with rows i think it would equate to ROWS 20 TO 30. So the numbers would need to be manipulated inside the driver implementation. But still, very interesting.

Comment: @srayner Firebird 3.0 will introduce the more SQL standard [OFFSET / FETCH](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/core/blob/master/doc/sql.extensions/README.offset_fetch.txt)