# How do I implement a Firebird driver for Zend Framework2?

Tags: sql, database, zend-framework2, firebird

The ZF2 Firebird PDO driver does produce correct SQL, see here;

[with Zend\Db\Sql\Select can I manipulate the order that the SQL parts are put together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568921/with-zend-db-sql-select-can-i-manipulate-the-order-that-the-sql-parts-are-put-to)

Therefore I would like to create a native ZF2 firebird driver. I think I need to sub-class the Zend\Db\Sql\Select class. But would I need to override other classes as well?

Comment: pdo_firebird and just pass it at the driver array key? There is no need to create a new database abstraction layer imo.

Comment: as stated pdo_firebird does not produce correct sql. I'm thinking of creating a native driver that does not use pdo.